# Can I using LINQ return a List<Person> from a List<String>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Can I using LINQ return a `List<Person>` from a `List<String>` like the following:

```
// this is not valid code, just to explain the idea
var persons = new string[] {"Tom", "Adam"}.ToList<Person>(str => Name = str);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var people = new string[] {"Tom", "Adam"}
    .Select(str => new Person {Name = str});
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<Person>`. If you'd like a list:

```
var people = new string[] {"Tom", "Adam"}
    .Select(str => new Person {Name = str})
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
var names = new []{"Tom", "Adam"};
var persons = from name in names
              select new Person {Name = name};
```

and then you will have to do:

```
var personsList = persons.ToList();
```

in order to *materialize* the LINQ expression into a `List<Person>` instance.